# OrchardCMS Theme broken, need to get to the Dash

Tags: orchardcms

I have a broken site ATM and the theme layout is stuffed, I need to get to the dashboard by entering the direct link, does anyone have a sample that I can use.

Comment: That isn't particularly helpful... any error logs? what theme is it? is it a custom theme? what have you tried?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the direct link". `/admin`?

Comment: Forced an update of the engine to the lastest version, and found that I needed to make changes to the user roles and configuration, made the changes in the database and got it working.
What I found is that the user now needs to be part of a role, in the database made the change to the user giving them role ID of 1, this allowed me to go to the <Site>\admin page to get to the dashboard, from there I could reset to a default theme and get the site back up and running again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forced an update of the engine to the lastest version, and found that I needed to make changes to the user roles and configuration, made the changes in the database and got it working. What I found is that the user now needs to be part of a role, in the database made the change to the user giving them role ID of 1, this allowed me to go to the \admin page to get to the dashboard, from there I could reset to a default theme and get the site back up and running again